# Javascript convert array to object with alternate index as keys and values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of below type

```
["key1","value1","key2","value2"]
```

I want to convert it into below array of object

```
[{key1:"value1"},{key2:"value2"}]
```

What can be the shortest way to achieve this.

Edit - i have tried below approach of first seperating keys and values and then merging them

```
  let a = ["key1","value1","key2","value2"]

let firstArr = [], secondArr = [];

a.forEach( (a,i) => {
  (i % 2 === 0) ? firstArr.push(a) : secondArr.push(a);
})
```

then merging firstArr and secondArr

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: _"What can be the shortest way..."_ - Define _"shortest"_. A simple `for` loop with `+= 2` would already do the job.

Comment: You made a questionable choice, the Fullstack Guy code does not work if the number of entries is odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can check the current index, if it is even it is a key else it is a value:

```js
const data = ["key1","value1","key2","value2"];

const arrObjs = data.reduce((acc, o, i, arr) => {
  if(i % 2 === 0){;
    acc.push({[o]: arr[i + 1]})
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(arrObjs);
```

Comment: @MisterJojo It is not stated what the result should be if there are an odd number of elements, or if that is even valid.